# Visual Studio trying to include linux headers despite if statement

Tags: c++, linux, windows, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

I am attempting to create a robust header file that will compile on both windows and linux without need for changes. To this end I have an if statement in my includes that looks like

```
#if (!defined(__WINDOWS__))
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#endif
```

I am having problems with visual studio still attempting to include these headers despite the if statement resulting in errors like

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/time.h'
```

Is there a way to resolve this issue without removing all the linux blocks of code from the header?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__WINDOWS__` is defined by `windows.h`. So you have a circularity. Use this instead:

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
#   if defined(_WIN64)
        /*64 bit windows*/
#   else
        /*32 bit windows*/
#   endif
#endif
```

Yes, _WIN32 **is** defined on 64 bit windows. I kid you not.