# *Where* to replace ```sys/time.h``` header dependency in Windows?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I've been trying to install a package on my Windows machine using Git bash. I encounter the error:  `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/time.h': No such file or directoryerror'`, which multiple StackOverflow questions try to address (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494356/how-to-use-gettimeofday-or-something-equivalent-with-visual-studio-c-2008), [here2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494356/how-to-use-gettimeofday-or-something-equivalent-with-visual-studio-c-2008) and [here3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25615571/how-to-use-sys-time-h-in-windows)). There's no shortage of possible answers but no updated/current solutions.

By way, I came across a possible solution, offered by the link below, which suggests to create 3 files, `time.h`, `times.h` and `times.cpp`. The problem is, it's unclear to me where to place these three files - the author suggests to put them in the same "project folder" but this is unclear to me. I created a folder `sys` with these three files in the same project and tried to compile, to no avail. Is there something simple I'm overlooking?

https://www.codefull.net/2015/12/systime-h-replacement-for-windows/

Comment: which package are you trying to install?

Comment: It is a small polymer modeling package PolymerCpp (https://github.com/kmdouglass/PolymerCpp) . Because it is not so popular, I couldn't find a Windows binary from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: And what are you using to compile/link your project? Are you using a makefile or something? How do you turn the source code into executable code?

Comment: There is a makefile, but I am using setup.py to deploy the Python application

Comment: No idea if this will work: throw the .h files in the include directory, and the .ccp file in the PolymerCPP/core directory. Looks like the makefile should handle the rest. Maybe.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I gave it a shot, but am still encountering the same error. Rather than installing the entire package, I've also tried just compiling the shared library, but  since I am using Git for windows I encounter an ```incompatible versions of cygwin DLL``` error

Comment: You could try this methond: create a robust header file.You could refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384020/visual-studio-trying-to-include-linux-headers-despite-if-statement) .  #if defined(_WIN32)
#   if defined(_WIN64)
        /*64 bit windows*/
#   else
        /*32 bit windows*/
#   endif
#endif